# Viewers (per Link) jump to current date when they open file

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, reference, match, google-sheets-formula

I have a table in Google Sheets in the format:

```
A     B     C

Day  Date  inventory demand

Day2 Date2 inventory demand
```

etc.

Others are required to fill in inventory and demand every day. Thus, it would be helpful if they open the sheet they jump always to the current date. This could be done over HYPERLINK or code. However, as I am informed onOpen works for the editor, however not for viewers. As this is currently the case. When I open the file I jump to the current date, however people viewing and editing the file per link do not.

Could somebody please help me? Thank you.

I also do not understand, why creating a cell that jumps to the current date as an alternative does not work. 
I tried various variations of

```
=HYPERLINK("l i n k&range=B"&MATCH("TODAY",B1:B1500,0),"Jump to today")
```

or

```
=HyperLink("LINK&range=B" &Match(Today(),B6:B,1),"JUMP to Today")
```

---

```
// jump to current date
function onOpen() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("B:B");
var values = range.getValues();  
var day = 24*3600*1000;  
var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);  
var ssdate; 
for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
try {
ssdate = values[i][0].getTime()/day;
}
catch(e) {
}
if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == today) {
 sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(i,0,1,1));
 break;
}    
}
}
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13LB4vV4REZ2sx9aWgupytS5XZ-MpOf-zsqW_L1788MU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
=HYPERLINK("#gid=0&range=B"&MATCH(TODAY(); B6:B; 0)+5; "zu heute")
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

I found the options: Edit Triggers

To manually create an installable trigger through a dialog in the script editor, follow these steps:

From the script editor, choose Edit > Current project's triggers.

Click the link that says: No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.

Under Run, select the name of function you want to trigger.

Under Events, select either Time-driven or the Google App that the script is bound to (for example, From spreadsheet).

Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create (for example, an Hour timer that runs Every hour or an On open trigger).

Optionally, click Notifications to configure how and when you are contacted by email if your triggered function fails.

Click Save.

[Google Explanation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)